# MySQL show counts of ranges

Tags: mysql

Similar questions have been asked but no solutions have worked for me.

I have a table with the sizes of apartments:

```
|  size  |
----------
10
15
23
54
9
16
32
```

I want to be able to build a list with the number of apartments in each size range, eg:

```
| range | quantity |
--------------------
0-9     | 1
10-19   | 3
20-29   | 1
30-39   | 1
40-49   | 0
50-59   | 1
```

What is the cleanest way of doing this in MySQL?

Comment: http://www.wagonhq.com/sql-tutorial/creating-a-histogram-sql I think this article has a pretty clean way.

Comment: If you suggest some ways, perhaps we can advise on the cleanest. Otherwise, just wash hands regularly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't show empty values, but does split the rest of the values out:

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(FLOOR(size/10)*10, "-", (FLOOR(size/10)*10 + 10)) AS "Range",
    COUNT(*) AS "Quantity"
FROM test
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Adapted from here:
https://flylib.com/books/en/2.305.1/categorizing_non_categorical_data.html

Result:

```
Range  Quantity
0-10    1
10-20   3
20-30   1
30-40   1
50-60   1
```